# Dart Map with String key, compare with ignore case

Tags: dart

Does the Map class in Dart have a way to ignore case if the key is a string?

Eg.

```
var map = new Map<String, int>(/*MyComparerThatIgnoresCase*/);
map["MyKey"] = 42;
var shouldBe42 = map["mykey"];
```

In C# the Dictionary constructor takes a comparer like the comment above. What is the canonical way to do this in Dart?

Comment: Change how map keys are checked for equality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236193/change-how-map-keys-are-checked-for-equality

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maps in Dart have an internal method that compares keys for equality. So far as I know, you can't change this for the default `Map` class. However, you can use the very similar core `LinkedHashMap` class, which not only allows, but requires that you specify a key equality method. You can check out more about LinkedHashMaps at https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:collection.LinkedHashMap

```dart
LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap(
    (a, b) => a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase(),
    (key) => key.toLowerCase().hashCode
);

map['Foo'] = 'bar';
print(map['foo']);   //bar
```

Comment: If you do new Map<X,Y>() you actually get a LinkedHashMap. This can be seen in the factory contructor for Map (factory Map() = LinkedHashMap<K, V>;)

Comment: There is a function in quiver that does equals while ignoring case. The current implementation just makes them into lowercase but it might be better to use that than providing your own. The code then becomes:
`import 'package:quiver/strings.dart';`
`new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>(equals: equalsIgnoreCase, hashCode: (String k) => k.toLowerCase().hashCode);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27786241/116891, below, is the more efficient answer (according to the docstring of `CanonicalizedMap` itself).

Answer (score 8):

The way to create a `HashMap` with a custom equals function (and corresponding custom hashCode function) is to use the optional parameters on the `HashMap` constructor:

```dart
new HashMap<String,Whatever>(equals: (a, b) => a.toUpperCase() == b.toUpperCase(),
                             hashCode: (a) => a.toUpperCase().hashCode);
```

I really, really recommend finding a way to not do the toUpperCase on every operation!

Comment: This is also a correct answer but LinkedHashMap is the default implementation you get for a Map. Found the docs for HashMap here https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:collection.HashMap

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using `package:collection`'s [`CanonicalizedMap`](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/collection/1.1.0/index.html#collection/dart-pkg-collection.CanonicalizedMap) class. This class is explicitly designed to support maps with "canonical" versions of keys, and is slightly more efficient than passing a custom equality and hash code method to a normal `Map`.

Comment: This is the preferred method according to its docstring:

```/// A map whose keys are converted to canonical values of type `C`.
///
/// This is useful for using case-insensitive String keys, for example. It's
/// more efficient than a [LinkedHashMap] with a custom equality operator
/// because it only canonicalizes each key once, rather than doing so for each
/// comparison.
///
/// By default, `null` is allowed as a key. It can be forbidden via the
/// `isValidKey` parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Dart has a nifty
`CaseInsensitiveEquality().equals(String a, String b)`
in their
`import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`
It returns a bool and worked great for me when I was translating strings back to an enum.  You do have to run `dart pub add collection` at the command line to install the package.