# Change how map keys are checked for equality

Tags: dart

I have the following code:

```
class KeyClass {
  int property;

  KeyClass(this.property);
}

void main() {
  KeyClass kc1 = KeyClass(1);
  KeyClass kc2 = KeyClass(2);

  Map<KeyClass, String> map = Map();
  map[kc1] = 'hello';
  map[kc2] = 'world';
  ...
}
```

My goal is to for the following two lines to get the same value from my `map`:

```
print(map[kc1]);          // prints 'hello'
print(map[KeyClass(1)]);  // prints 'null', should print 'hello' too!
```

Is this possible in Dart language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `Map` implementation is a `LinkedHashMap`, so it relies on computing hash codes for the keys.  There are a few ways you could make your keys compare equal:

1. Implement `KeyClass.operator ==` and `KeyCode.hashCode`:

   ```dart
   class KeyClass {
     int property;

     KeyClass(this.property);

     bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
       return runtimeType == other.runtimeType && property == other.property;
     }

     int get hashCode => property.hashCode;
   }
   ```
2. Use `LinkedHashMap` directly. `LinkedHashMap`'s constructor allows providing custom callbacks for computing equality and hash codes:

   ```dart
   bool keyEquals(KeyClass k1, KeyClass k2) => k1.property == k2.property;
   int keyHashCode(KeyClass k) => k.property.hashCode;

   Map<KeyClass, String> map = LinkedHashMap<KeyClass, String>(
     equals: keyEquals,
     hashCode: keyHashCode,
   );
   ```