# Dart - Map with Set as key

Tags: dart, collections

I'm trying to construct a `Map` object with `Set` as keys:

```dart
final myObject = <Set<MyType1>, MyType2>{};
```

I can successfully insert new values in my object

```dart
myObject[{myType1}] = myType2;
```

However, I cannot get back anything from it as 2 sets with the same values won't be consider equal:

```dart
{0} == {0}; // <- false
```

```dart
myObject[{myType1}]; // <- null
```

---

Is there something built-in that could allow me to use a `Map<Set<T>, U>` object?

Comment: Alternatively use a `LinkedHashMap` constructor and provide callbacks to compute key equality and hash codes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237026/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create your own class that wraps a Set with your own equals and hashCode. Then the problem is solved.

A very rough example to demonstrate my idea:

```
class MySet<T> {
  final Set<T> inner;
  ...

  @override
  bool equals(other) => setEquals(this, other); // https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/setEquals.html

  @override
  int hashCode => ...
}
```

P.S. The equals/hashCode of a Set is not implemented as whether the contents are the same, because that would be very costly.

Comment: Thank you, I already thought about that. But I was expecting that there would already be a `class OtherSet extends Set` that already supports the deep equal instead of creating a wrapper. What would be the override of the `hashCode` in your example?

Comment: @ValentinVignal maybe no imho. you can write your own hashcode, e.g. by XOR all hashcode of elements

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to extend any of the `Set` classes as they only have factory constructors. This would otherwise have been a clean way to implement a set with a custom notion of equality and hashing.

As an alternative, the [`HashMap` constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/HashMap/HashMap.html) accepts a custom hash and equality function which can be used:

```dart
Map<K, V> hashMapDeep<K extends Set, V>() => HashMap(
      equals: setEquals,
      hashCode: Object.hashAllUnordered,
    );
```

This uses [`Object.hashAllUnordered`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.0/dart-core/Object/hashAllUnordered.html) to create an order-independent has of the set and [`setEquals`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/setEquals.html) from Flutter for the equality comparison.